# Call variable in other function

Tags: php, oop, methods, mysqli

I want to call `$con` variable in other function.This variable contain my database connection so some query's run in my other function so I need call this `$con` variable in other function.I am new at PhP OOP so maybe my concept not Good.but please suggest plus give me solution.

**PHP**

```
    Class CORE 
 {  


      public function connect_database() 

       {


        $connection=mysqli_connect(host,user,"1234");

        $con = mysqli_select_db($connection,database);
       if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    }

      public function show_name()
        {

      $user = base64_decode($_SESSION['admin']);
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT full_name FROM admin_user WHERE user='".$user."'");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
           echo $row['full_name'];
      } 


        }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class a little:

```
Class CORE {  

    protected $con;
    public $error;


    public function get_con(){
      return $this->con;
    }

    public function connect_database(){

      connection=mysqli_connect(host,user,"1234");

      $this->con = mysqli_select_db($connection,database);
      if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->con)){
         $this->error = mysqli_connect_error();
      }

   }

   public function show_name(){

    $user = base64_decode($_SESSION['admin']);
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT full_name FROM admin_user WHERE    
    user='".$user."'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {echo $row['full_name'];} 
  }
}
```

Now create an instance of the class to check `$con` and `$error`:

```
$test = new CORE();
echo $test->get_con(); 
echo $test->error;
```

If `$con` gives no errors (and `$error` shows no error) use it in any other function by means of `$this->con`